# Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager Net Core allowing packages that are higher then target sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-core-2.1

So i have a project targeting Net Core 2.1 (specifically 2.1.500)

I also have a global.json which also has 2.1.500 in it.

Recently Microsoft updated to Net Core 2.2 but I don't want to move to that yet.

When I open Nuget Package Manager it shows me that there are updates available to some pacakges

[image]

the problem is that all of these packages are for 2.2 sdk and it completely ignores the fact that I am not targeting that.

This seems like a bug , because in the .Net Framework it would not suggest packages that were targeting an sdk higher than the one you were using.

Is this correct? should I report an issue to the Net Core team?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is correct. The libraries target the `.NETStandard2.0` not `.NET Core App 2.2` which means any `.NET Core` app that is compatible with the `.NET Standard 2.0` can use the libraries, regardless of the `.NET SDK` they are using.

For an example, take a look at `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` in the `Manage Nuget Packages` window in Visual Studio. It lists its dependencies as `.NETFramework,Version=v4.0`, which means it won't work in `.NET Core` or any earlier versions of the `.NET Framework`.

Additionally, if you try to install the `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` package in a `.NET Core` you will see an error in the Error List window:

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact 6.2.0' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project
>   target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be
>   fully compatible with your project.